# find duplicate words in a comma separated strings in a panda column and add various prefixes to them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe column that looks like the following but larger:

```
df=  pd.DataFrame(["Mina,is,good", "Dania,is,good,good", "Alice,is,good,good,good"]
                 columns=['a'])
```

I want the output to look like:

```
df_output=  pd.DataFrame(["Mina,is,good", "Dania,is,A-good,Y-good", "Alice,is,A-good,Y-good,Z-good"]
          columns=['a'])
```

So I want to add a prefix if a word is repeated, but there are also three different prefixes:
if a word is repeated once, I want to add ("A-", "Y-"), and if a word is repeated twice, I want to add ("A-", "Y-", "Z-")

Thank you in advance

Comment: what if the word repeats many times i.e fore than 3,4,5 times?

Comment: no, the maximum number of repetition is 2, similar to the example

Comment: does the repetitions only occurs consecutively ?

Comment: yeah it only happens right after one another. but there are rows where there are two different words that are repeated, like " Mina,is,is,good,good,good", and I want the same to happen for both repetitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a custom function as below using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
def fun(x):
    d = {0:'A-',1:'Y-',2:'Z-'} # mapping dictionary
    s = pd.Series(x.split(',')) #split each row as list and treat as series
    mask = s.duplicated(keep=False) #check for cases only which are duplicated
    s[mask] = s[mask].groupby(s).cumcount().map(d) + s[mask]
    return ','.join(s)

df['a'].apply(fun)
```

---

```
0                     Mina,is,good
1           Dania,is,A-good,Y-good
2    Alice,is,A-good,Y-good,Z-good
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. is there a way of dealing with items that are repeated but we do not want to add prefix to them. some of the rows are like for example : "D,D,D,Mina,is,good,good,D,D,D". and I do not want to add the prefixes to "D".

Comment: thank you for your reply. is there a way of dealing with items that are repeated but we do not want to add prefix to them. some of the rows are like for example : "D,D,D,Mina,is,good,good,D,D,D". and I do not want to add the prefixes to "D"

Comment: @tina.mario i am not sure how that can be done and the original question didn't include this. Unfortunately I am out and will be available only tomorrow. It's better if you can ask a new question with the latest requirements. Thank you

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will open a new question.